# Creating a hash and using to_param to obfuscate ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like to be able to obfuscate the id's of objects in my app so that a URL can be shared, but not easily guessed.

I've gathered that I need to store a `hashed_id` in the database for the object, and that it may be possible to rewrite the `to_param` function to use that `hashed_id`in the URL but I'm having trouble getting it to work.

model:

```
  after_create :create_hashed_id

  def to_param
        self.hashed_id
  end

  def create_hashed_id
    self.update_attributes(:hashed_id => Digest::SHA1.hexdigest([Time.now, rand].join)[0,16])
  end
```

controller:

```
def show
    @upload = Upload.find_by_hashed_id(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @upload }
    end
  end
```

The object gets created with a hash_id attribute but when I try and invoke the show method it looks like it's looking in the `id` column instead of the `hashed_id` column.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean the "self" in to_param? That doesn't change anything.

Comment: On the console I can't get a result from Upload.find_by_hashed_id. I get an error:
NoMethodError: undefined method `find_by_hashed_id'

Comment: I'm still running into a wall on this... is 'hashed_id' a protected name? Is there any reason why there isn't a `find_by_hashed_id` method where there is a `find_by_email` and `find_by_name` etc... ?

Comment: Did you try changing it?

Comment: I did try changing it and am still running into the same problem.

Comment: `self` or no `self` makes no difference here. Are you sure `hashed_id` was migrated to your database? I don't think `hashed_id` is protected, but have you tried a different attribute name to make sure?